# Numpy:convert index to label

Tags: python, numpy

```
array = [1, 0, 2, ..., 0, 1, 0]

LABELS = ["BKG", "ALERT", "FALL"]
```

I want to convert the `array` to the `label` of the corresponding index .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,0,2,0,1,0], dtype = 'object')
labels = [ "BKG", "ALERT", "FALL" ]

for i in range(len(labels)):
        a[a == i] = labels[i]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
array(['ALERT', 'BKG', 'FALL', 'BKG', 'ALERT', 'BKG'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension will do nicely:

```
array = [1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0]
labels = ["BKG", "ALERT", "FALL"]

result = [labels[i] for i in array]
```

Output:

```
['ALERT', 'BKG', 'FALL', 'BKG', 'ALERT', 'BKG']
```